# retrieve data from access using php odbc throws error in parameter line

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract data from a table in access database using odbc connection and php. I have written the code below but it gives error **"Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
**Description:** [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'table1.col_date"**

```
<?php $cn = new com("ADODB.Connection");
 $rs = new com("ADODB.Recordset");

$cn->open("dsn=odbcconnection");
?>
<form action = "thispage.php" method = "post">
Enter Date : <input type = "text" name = "datadate" />
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" /> 
</form>
<?php
$datadate = isset($_REQUEST['datadate']) ? $_REQUEST['datadate'] : null; ?>

<?php $sql = "select col_date, sum(qty1), sum(qty2) from table1
              where  table1.col_date = '".$datadate."'
              group by col_date
              order by col_date";

// Execute query
$rs = $cn->execute($sql);
```

I think there is a problem in only parameter line table1.col_date = $datadate because when I replace $datadate with static date like table1.col_date = #05/08/2012# , it displays output correctly for the date

Comment: and what about format? is table.col_date type date?

Comment: you should try yyy-mm-dd

Comment: im getting this error even before selecting date..so I don't think it is related to format...i tried changing `table1.col_date = '$datedate'` but still the same but if I change it to `table1.col_date = #01/05/2012#`, it correctly displays output for 1st May, 2012

Comment: $_REQUEST['datadate'] suggests a query string parameter. Is that populated and spelt correctly? Are you posting to this page or an actual `thispage.php` file?

Comment: yes it is spelled correctly..Now I'm getting error "data type mismatch" after editing code as per your answer with double quotes(i updated in question)

Comment: i'm posting to this page itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that is either you are using query string parameters posting to the current page which are empty or you are getting confused with POST. Try the following

If you are posting to the page itself then do the following

```
<form action = "<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method = "post">
```

then change the the to the following:

```
$datadate = isset($_POST['datadate']) ? $_POST['datadate'] : null; ?>
```

Lastly make the change as previously stated

Replace the `[table1.col_date]` with `[table1].[col_date]` or remove the brackets completely
and try the following

```
<?php $sql = "select col_date, qty1, qty2 from table1 where  [table].[col_date]= '".$datadate."' group by col_date order by col_date";
```

Comment: still I'm getting `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'table1.col_date = '.'`..please see original question i edited my code above as per your answer.....

Comment: Thanks JLC007 for your help but it doesn't seem to work. I will keep trying anyway.

Comment: After a long effort, i managed to make it work. I used `[table].[col_date] = #$datadate#`